# When is ThreadLocal member initialized?

Tags: java, multithreading

In java, i have a class structure like

```
class A{
    ThreadLocal<B> myB;
    public A(){
      myB = new ThreadLocal<B>(){
         protected B initialValue(){
            return new B();
         }
      };
    }

    static class B{
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A();
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
          new Thread(a).start();
    }
}
```

As i understand the concept of ThreadLocal, each thread will have its own threadLocal object for myB.

Lets say A is being used by multiple threads (as given in main()).

Given that i am instantiating A only once,When will the myB member be created for each thread?

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand it so well. [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#142) to the rescue

Comment: @Raffaele : yes i did not! :) makes more sense now! Thank you!

Comment: Your example is messed up:  It has a ThreadLocal, myB, that is never assigned.  The constructor creates a new ThreadLocal, B, and does nothing with it.  Was the B in your constructor supposed to be myB perhaps?  And where is there any call to `get()` or `set()` the thread-local value?

Comment: @jameslarge : yes, it was a typo! thanks! :) calls to get-set are in the run() method which i have not shown...thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The first time the `get` method of a `ThreadLocal` is called by a thread, the `initialValue()` method that you defined is invoked, thus creating a new `B` instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `myB` that will get created many times. When you can `myB.get()`,  your `initialValue()` will be invoked to get a new value, if none has been `set` yet for that thread.

Comment: Thank you, for the instant reply! :)